# frame_support::traits::OnInitialize vs frame_support::traits::Hooks

Tags: traits, hook

Both of these have `on_initialize` calls. What's the difference? When is one run vs the other? Why are these separate concepts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding:

`Hooks` is for pallet level. The most common usage is:

```rust
#[pallet::hooks]
impl<T Config> Hooks for Pallet<T> {}
```

`OnInitialize` is for the runtime level. There are so many other hooks in `Hooks`, but sometimes the runtime only focuses on `on_initialize`.

And the following code does the same thing:

```rust
<frame_system::Pallet<T> as frame_support::traits::OnInitialize<_>>::on_initialize(0_u32.into());
<frame_system::Pallet<T> as frame_support::traits::Hooks<_>>::on_initialize(0_u32.into());
```